# Google maps Geometry Controls from GMaps Utility Library

Tags: controls, geometry, maps

i'm working on google maps in specifically on [geometry controls](http://gmaps-utility-library-dev.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/geometrycontrols/examples/test.html)

the point is, in this example when I click in line or polygon infowindow show up, but the language is english (by default I think) can I change the language?

in the tooltips i can replace the text, but in this particular case i have no place do replace it, this let me thinking that "language" is automatic, i'm wrong?

best regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you take a look at the reference here:

http://gmaps-utility-library-dev.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/geometrycontrols/docs/reference.html

it says that the html is generated from a template file. In the demo, that file is:

http://gmaps-utility-library-dev.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/geometrycontrols/examples/data/geometry_html_template.html

look at the source of this file, and you'll see that's its an html template. You can change the text in there-